# Is there an alternate way to display line item prices on a Shopify packing slip?

Tags: shopify, liquid

By default, Shopify's packing slip uses

```
{% if item.sku == line_item.sku %}
  {% assign final_price = line_item.final_price %}
{% endif %}
{% if final_price %}
  {{ final_price | money }}
{% endif %}
```

to display a line item's price on a packing slip. I have a client who needs to use the same sku for multiple products, and this has resulted in the wrong line item prices being displayed on some packing slips. Does anyone know of a way to display the line-item price without referencing an item's sku? I have already tried using product and variant id, title, etc. Variant barcode looks like it may work, but this client does not have barcodes for their products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the liquid objects available to you.

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shipping/setting-up-and-managing-your-shipping/packing-slips-variable-list

From that list I'm not sure if you can return the line_item.final_price value here.

But for the condition, i'd run it on variant_title

```
{% if item.variant_title == line_item.variant_title %}
  {% assign final_price = line_item.final_price %}
{% endif %}
{% if final_price %}
  {{ final_price | money }}
{% endif %}
```